# Castle Windsor Register by Convention - how to register generic Repository based on Entity?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, castle

This should be a general problem, i've searched but couldn't found any solution yet, if it is a dupe, please point me appropriate link.

So,
i have a generic repository to support several entites, for a moment i register it like bellow:

```
public class ExpensiveServiceInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        Register<EntityA>(container);
        Register<EntityB>(container);
        //etc etc 
        //when there is a new one should register it manually
    }

    void Register<T>(IWindsorContainer container) where T : Entity
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<IRepository<T>>()
            .ImplementedBy<Repository<T>>()
            .LifeStyle.Transient);
    }
}
```

Note:
Repository located on `Repositories` namespace
Entities located on `Entities` namespace, including the `Entity` baseclass of all entities

it is working fine, but i think it should be a better way, the more automatic way using registration by convention, so when i add a new entity on my project, windsor will automatically recognize it, and register repository for it. and one more question, how to ignore `Entity` (the base class) so it not registered on the container.

regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IRepository<>))
            .ImplementedBy(typeof(Repository<>))
            .LifeStyle.Transient);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();


        container.Register(Component.For(typeof(ICustomGenericRepository<>))
        .ImplementedBy(typeof(CustomGenericRepository<>))
        .LifeStyle.Transient);
```